# tikz plot coordinates decorations change between points

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, coordinates

I have a plot of coordinates

```
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates{ (-3.1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.3) (0,0) (1.8,0.64) (3,0.5)};
```

Is there a way to have the curve between (0,0) and (1.8, 0.64) painted thick?

I would just draw a second plot, but of course the smoothing is different when I omitt data.

Answer (score 4):

You could clip the second plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates{ (-3.1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.3) (0,0) (1.8,0.64) (3,0.5)};

        \begin{scope} 
            \clip(0,0) rectangle (1.8,0.64);
            \draw[thick] plot [smooth] coordinates{ (-3.1,-0.5) (-1.5,0.3) (0,0) (1.8,0.64) (3,0.5)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case this works, but what if the plot intersects itself? Then this would leave the intersection visible.